# How to get OkHttpClient and RestClient using ResourceManager (Azure SDK 2.8.0 onwards)

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

In older Azure SDK (1.41.2) ResourceManager class is inherited (from multiple level) from ServiceClient class. This ServiceClient class have methods like httpClient() to get OkHttpClient, restClient() to get RestClient.

But in new SDK (2.8.0) ResourceManager class have different inheritance hierarchy. And I could find way to get OkHttpClient and RestClient.
Please help me to migrate and get OkHttpClient and RestClient using ResourceManager in latest SDK.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you gone through this [github](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/blob/main/sdk/resourcemanager/docs/MIGRATION_GUIDE.md) article  for migrating to com.azure.resourcemanager.** from com.microsoft.azure.management.**

Comment: Thanks for response. I went through above link. Its talking about creating custom Http Client. I want similar class as https://azure.github.io/ref-docs/java/com/microsoft/rest/ServiceClient.html . It was present in older sdk to return okhhtpclient.